# Magento 2 - Syntax error on bin/magento support:backup:db

Tags: magento2, database, cli, backup

I am trying to get backup of DB using following command

```
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento support:backup:db
```

It is giving me syntax error:

```
sh: 2: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
Error: Command returned non-zero exit code:
`(/usr/bin/nice -n 15 /usr/bin/mysqldump -uxxxx -hxxxx  -p"xxxx" xxxx --skip-extended-insert  customer_entity customer_entity_varchar customer_address_entity customer_address_entity_varchar customer_grid_flat quote quote_address sales_order sales_order_address sales_order_grid 2>&1 | /usr/bin/php -r 'while ($line=fgets(STDIN)) {
           if (preg_match("/(^INSERT INTO\s+\S+\s+VALUES\s+)\((.*)\);$/",$line,$matches)) {
               $row = str_getcsv($matches[2],",","\x27");
               foreach($row as $key=>$field) {
                   if ($field == "NULL") {
                       continue;
                   } elseif ( preg_match("/[A-Z]/i", $field)) {
                       $field = md5($field . rand());
                   }
                   $row[$key] = "\x27" . $field . "\x27";
               }
               echo $matches[1] . "(" . implode(",", $row) . ");\n";
               continue;
           }
           echo $line;
       };';
```

I didn't tried this command before and never faced this type of error, can anyone guide me how can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not seen support:backup:db command yet.

To take the backup of database, the command i have used is

```
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:backup --db
```

Comment: I will check, will let you know

Comment: It worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the below command it is also used for the tacking backups in magento 2

```
php bin/magento setup:backup --db --code --media
```

Through this command magento will backup your required data (source_code, database, Media files) to the **`Magento_root/var/backup`** directory from there you can download it again & also can rollback if it is needed in future.

Please [refer this devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-backup.html#instgde-cli-uninst-back).

Comment: I will check, will let you know

Comment: Thanks for the answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

In Adobe cloud, php bin/magento support:backup:db

would output that DB exported successfully and it should be available under var/support

you can use
php bin/magento support:backup:db -vvv to get exact file path of export as well if export path is not specified.